# Get information about authenticated user

Tags: eventbrite

I may be missing something simple, but I am having difficulty in getting information about the logged in user.  I've successfully authenticated using OAuth and have obtained an access_token.  I understand that a user_key is required to get access to private data.  I don't seem to be able to figure out how to get this.  I'm just starting with EventBrite integration so I'm not completely familiar with it.  I've integrated with Facebook in the past.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what platform/environment/language?

Answer (score 0):

See the bit about access_tokens and request headers here:
http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/authentication/

Or, use one of the API client libraries to make the request for you:
http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/libraries/

Comment: The question was, how do I obtain the user_key.  I've been all through this page, and it doesn't not mention "how" to get it.  Just that you "need" it to get private data.  I'm working this from a windows phone application and so cannot use the client libraries.

Comment: You don't.  A user_key is just another type of access token.